How to archive a website with occasional PHP errors?
I am trying to archive a website that will soon vanish. I tried wget and httrack.
The problem is that the website returns PHP errors (database connection error) from time to time and the downloaded page is worthless. In any case the HTTP status is 200 so wget thinks that the download is okay. The error string is predictable and easy to match.
Is there a way to tell wget or httrack that it should re-download if the response contains a particular string/expression? Are there better web archiving tools in 2024?

Can you edit the question to include details of the "PHP errors" which are returned, and if a HTTP response error code is returned when a truncated page is downloaded? man wget shows the --retry-on-http-error which can cause a retry on a HTTP error code which wget normally considers fatal, but can't see an option to parse the text of the downloaded page to trigger a retry.

The tool to use is wget with Lua hooks from ArchiveTeam. Lua hook can inspect the whole contents of the downloaded file and instruct wget to download again if a pattern matches.
https://github.com/ArchiveTeam/wget-lua

Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.
